# Vertically align NSAttributedString with different sized characters

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I have been googling around for a while now and I am still surprised in iOS6 there is no way to **vertically** align an `NSAttributedString` with chars of different sizes? In particular I am trying to vertically align it as a `UIButton` title property, is that feasible?

Comment: Vertically align in what? CGRect, UITextView? Here's a CGRect tutorial: http://www.gameaid.org/2012/11/vertically-align-an-nsstring-in-an-nsrect/

Comment: Actually it is a UIButton title property, you are right I didn't specify that in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you gave is for NSRect, not CGRect.